# Angular2: making an iframe src safe using a directive

Tags: javascript, angular, xss

I am trying to apply a sanitized src attribute to an iframe, directly it works fine, but when putting it all in an attribute directive, it refuses to play ball. Here is the directive code, and the error message that appears

```
import { OnInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import {  DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl} from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Directive({
    selector: '[resume]'
})
export class ResumeDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('resume') inputLink: string;

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let _url: string = this.inputLink + '#zoom=100';

        let resumeUrl: SafeResourceUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(_url);

        // this.el.nativeElement.src = resumeUrl.toString(); // same result
        this.render.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'src', _url);
       // using 'srcdoc' or setElementAttribute brings same results
     }
}
```

I get error: `SafeValue must use [property]=binding: /theurl/x.pdf#zoom=100 (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `@HostBinding()` - not sure if this will work though

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[resume]'
})
export class ResumeDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input('resume') inputLink: string;

    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private el: ElementRef, private render: Renderer) {

    }

    @HostBinding('src')
    resumeUrl:any;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let _url: string = this.inputLink + '#zoom=100';

        this.resumeUrl = this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(_url);
     }
}
```

`this.render.setElementProperty` doesn't care about sanitized values, it just calles to DOM APIs and passes the sanitized value as-is.

Comment: yup, faster answer I ever got that actually worked :) thanks

Comment: what would the html look like